# What cities have very stable temperatures that are over 19 degrees centigrade all year round?

Tags: weather-and-climate, cities

What cities have very stable temperatures that are over 19 degrees centigrade all year round?

According to holiday-weather.com Guayaquil in Ecuador does:

http://www.holiday-weather.com/guayaquil/averages

I am looking for a world wide list.

Comment: Most cities in the tropics, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/World_map_indicating_tropics_and_subtropics.png .

Comment: As well as, many cities in the subtropics.

Comment: Singapore. Bring an umbrella and face mask, though.